# SQL Cannot restore database on YOUNGER server version

Tags: sql-server

I made DB backup on 15.00.2255 and try to restore it on 15.00.4188 but it fails, any ideas?
[image: ssms]

Comment: Can you connect to the original host running `15.00.2255`, Ravahr, and post the output for `PRINT @@VERSION;` please?

Comment: Was the backup from SQL Server managed instance? Seems same scenario as https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2020/01/03/sql-server-sql-azure-managed-instance-restore-error-the-database-was-backed-up-on-a-server-running-version-15-00-2000/

Answer (score 10):

> I made DB backup on 15.00.2255 and try to restore it on 15.00.4188 but it fails, any ideas?

The error:

> The database was backed up .... version **15.00.2255**. That version is incompatible ... running version **15.00.4188** ...

The general understanding is that there should be no problems backing up from an older version to a newer version which is generally true. There are caveats which rarely, if ever, see the light of day. The common mistake made is that the **SQL Instance Version Number** must be larger/newer, which isn't the case (which is why it makes the error a little misleading, though technically still true). This compares the database physical version, not the server version, which is what makes this error occur, thus the 15.00.2255 on disk version is larger than the 15.00.4188.

This data can be gleaned from the `RESTORE HEADERONLY` command against the backup from the 15.00.2255 version, the results you want are under the column of DatabaseVersion.

If you compare that with the value of Database Version from the output of:

```
DBCC TRACEON(3604)
DBCC DBTABLE(master)
```

Ex: database version = 904

It should show the version in the backup is larger, thus the error.

There was no released SQL Box (On Prem) minor version 2255. I did not check any managed version (MI, SQLDB, etc.) numbers but most likely it's from one of those which is known that it's not possible to restore back to box/on prem.